# Display Products for Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

> I created a Wordpress page that must display the **products** that I've created using **Woocommerce Plugin**. It seems like it has it's own **Shop Page** so I tried to customize it (it has different template) but failed since I am just a beginner in Wordpress. So I tried making my own Wordpress page (just like what I said at the first line) having the same template with other **menu options**. So it's good. The problem is I cannot make the products show. So I searched and installed a **Display Product for Woocommerce Plugin** so that I can call the products, on the webpage that I created, using **shortcodes**. Unfortunately, there is no single products that shows in my page. Any suggestions with this?

Comment: It is a wordpress related topic. This site is about getting answers. I want an answer to my problem. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this Shortcode `[products]` on a new page. It showed me all the products i had in my woocommerce store.

Let me know if that fulfills your needs.

Comment: welcome, you can make the same as answer if it worked for you and the answer for the issue is correct. Happy to help.